# Sharepoint List permissions strange behavior

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a sharepoint list where i want to get my datas but when i try to access it by code it says to me "Access Denied" and with "Elevated Privilege" i can see i have 614 items (by using items.ItemCount not items.count ) in it but when i try to get them i can't.

Here is the code i'm using

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
  using(SPSite site = new SPSite("http://mysite/"))
  {
    using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
    SPList list = web.Lists["mylist"];
    SPListItemCollection items = list.Items;
    for (int i = 0;i <list.ItemCount; i++)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(items[i].Name);
    }
    }
  }
});
```

I also tried to use the getitems(query) like this

```
SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
```

The result is the same. (Note that the query works in CAML Builder)

Comment: I don't see any actual query made. Have you tried this? [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457534.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457534.aspx) What does your app return when trying to access data from the list?

Comment: i just put the line where i use the query but in my code the query is defined before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code inside SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges block  runs under the Application Pool Account of your web application.This permission should suffice in most cases to overcome all security restrictions.

In your case if the app pool account doesnt have any permission to that site collection, it will throw access denied.I would suggest trying impersonating a site collection administrator like below,

```
SPUserToken token = oWeb.AllUsers["[AdministratorLoginName]"].UserToken;
using(SPSite site = new SPSite("http://mysite/",token))
  {
    using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
    SPList list = web.Lists["mylist"];
    SPListItemCollection items = list.Items;
    for (int i = 0;i <list.ItemCount; i++)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(items[i].Name);
    }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yep! I just found the solution yesterday evening. You're right :)